# Enable/disable datepicker with checkbox

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsbutton, nsdatepicker

I am trying to enable and disable a datepicker with a checkbox, but I can not. What's wrong?

```
if ([checkBox state]==NSOnState) {
        [datePicker isEnabled];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-isEnabled` method is asking if the date picker is enabled.  It doesn't change anything. You use `-setEnabled:` to change the state.  For example:

```
[datePicker setEnabled:([checkBox state]==NSOnState)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Datepicker Input ID into annother ID with $(object).attr('id','new_id'), so the Datepicker is can't detect the input box. 
ex :

it would be easiest way :D *or it would be stupid way :), but it works